# How to remove if condition from my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: swift, uitableview, fetch

I have "fetchData" method which fills my "imagesArray":

```
func fetchData(){

    let imageQuery = PFUser.query()
    imageQuery?.whereKey("username", containedIn: namesArray)

    imageQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                print("\(object["username"] as! String)")

                self.imagesArray.append(object["image"] as! PFFile)
                if self.imagesArray.count == self.namesArray.count {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    print("Names Order: \(self.namesArray)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I have tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method which uses this array to fill UIImageView instance:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ChatsCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]

    if imagesArray.count == namesArray.count && self.imagesLoaded == false{
        imagesArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.imageView?.image = image
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.imagesLoaded = true
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Actually I use if condition for waiting my array "imagesArray" to be filled by query of another method and I use variable "imagesLoaded" to prevent infinite call of reloadData method.
How can I write this method without if condition?

Comment: If you want to _improve_ working code, try [codereview.se]

Comment: You should probably load every images and then do a tableView.reloadData()